# Java Comparator multiple params

Tags: java, comparator

I'm trying to create an Comparator on my custom type.

```
Type {
    int state = 0; // can be 0 or 1
    String name = ""; // can be anything
}
```

I'm trying to sort the list so, that at first, on the top of list are items with one state and on the bottom the other state.

And in second step, items in both section (section 1: state 0, section 2: state 1), are sorted alphabetically.

I've tried this:

```
    @Override
    public int compare(Type i1, Type i2) {
        boolean a = i1.state == 1;
        boolean b = i2.state == 1;
        if (a && b) {
            return i1.name.compareTo(i2.name);
        } else if (a && !b) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

But item's get kind of randomized with each item state change.

List with these items:

```
name : A B C D E F G H I J K
state: 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

should be listed like this:

```
B 0
E 0
G 0
H 0
K 0
A 1
C 1
D 1
F 1
I 1
J 1
```

Have anybody an idea how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: please say what is the Type token there in the first step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code breaks when both states are equal to zero. You could fix it by using this condition

```
if (a == b) ...
```

instead of

```
if (a && b)
```

...or try this instead:

```
@Override
public int compare(Type i1, Type i2) {
    int res = i1.state - i2.state;
    if (res == 0) {
        return i1.name.compareTo(i2.name);
    } else {
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh god, I'm so unable to think today. Thanks. It's clear as day, when I think about it like this now...

Comment: I'd also suggest to have an `enum` for state instead of using just integers

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement `Comparable` and put the same logic in the `compareTo` method?